# Why doesn't this GET request not return any data?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch an XML file from a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

```
$('#getBucketObjects').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $.get('http://CLOUDBUCKET.storage.googleapis.com/', function (data) {
  console.log(data)
  })
})
```

But it does not log anything. Why is that? This is a standard GET request to a web site, which should always return something (provided there is a HTML page there)?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? If you add `console.log('click')` inside the `.click` callback, does it get logged?

Comment: The `$.get()` operation is probably failing. You are only handling the success case. Use `$.get(...).done(function() { /* success */ }).fail(function() { /* failure */ });` to property catch success and failure cases.

Comment: omfg.. I forgot to do document.ready

Comment: So it doesn't not return no data?